# How do you type a line containing a single dot (.) in ed?

Tags: bash, sed, editor

\.  doesn't work.  a single dot (.) ends the command and cant be recognized.

Please don't tell me; use sed or echo . >> file.   Is there a way to do it with ed ?

Comment: ... see [How can I insert a lone dot on a line using ed's "insert" command?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/551196/how-can-i-insert-a-lone-dot-on-a-line-using-eds-insert-command)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe type "dot space" (or some other character) then dot then edit the line to remove the trailing character

```sh
touch afile
ed -s afile <<END
a
foo
.x
bar
.
-1s/x//
wq
END
```

then

```sh
$ cat -A afile
foo$
.$
bar$
```